# Getting iTunes artwork for an application

Tags: objective-c, ios, itunes

Is it possible (through some API) to get the artwork of an application given its iTunes id? For example for four square:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/foursquare/id306934924?mt=8

I'd like to get the link for the main Artwork of fourSquare shown on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on the first answer, you do a lookup on the id.  Just add the iTunes ID to the end of this query and tweak the country code if you are looking for a different storefront.

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?country=us&id=

eg

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?country=us&id=306934924

From the JSON results you need to dig out the "screenshotUrls".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes. [Be an iTunes Affiliate and use their SDK.](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)